# not able to install npm in ubuntu 18.04, E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am trying sudo apt install npm. not able to install.

```
sudo npm cache clean --force

sudo apt install npm, sudo apt-get install npm

sudo apt install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

> ```
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
>        Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

Comment: I think we have to set path after updateing node. In my case I update to vesrion 12 from 8.it got resolved after setting the path in bash.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you dont have nodejs installed already.

```
nodejs but it is not going to be installed
```

You need to install nodejs first.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```